# Show / Hide Divs

Tags: jquery, forms, html

I am trying to do the following.

Have two forms on page,

- [  form 1 ]
- [  form 2 ]

Essentially look at fiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/ozzy/S9nX7/1/

I want form 2 to be **hidden** on page load.

If user clicks **yes** on **form 1**, it takes them to new page
If user clicks **no** on **form 1**, it hides form 1 and shows form 2

I am buggered if I can work out the js to do this.
Hopefully using jquery slide , with easing... I have looked on jQuery site, and at slide up down, toggle show etc but.. am lost is there a simple solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code.
http://www.jsfiddle.net/S9nX7/4/

I have added the required css, and the required jQuery. I have cleaned up your html.

To hide the div#b on page load, use css: `#b{ display:none; }`

To hide `div#a` and show `div#b` when you click `a.no`, use jQuery. If you want sliding transitions, replace the jQuery hide/show with slides or whatever effect you want.

```
$("a.no").click(function(){
                 $("#a").hide();
                 $("#b").show();
                 return false;

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my fork at http://www.jsfiddle.net/QHBa8/

Essentially upon clicking no (the `onclick` event) you want to hide div `a` and show div `b`.  Using the jQuery id selector (`$('#a')` and `$('#b')`) you can get references to your divs and then call jQuery methods on them, such as `show()` and `hide()`.

In the example code its all inline, you'd want to call out to a javascript function to do the actual work.

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution? Yes.  Refactor your design and use two pages, one for each form.  The solution you're looking for?  No.

Comment: Man, sometimes you guys have no sense of humor.  ;)

Comment: If you had said 'Refactor your design to use one page for each form field, such that the user is presented with a form divided into twenty or so 'simple' steps.' then I would have voted this up. Instead, I did nothing :P